# How to populate a dictionary with 2 split strings in VB 2017

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, split

I have 2 string, both split by ("   ") and both around 40 different sub strings, first one called dick is the would-be keys, and the other one called dicv is the would-be values, how can I fill a dictionary with those?

I tried this:

```
    Dim dicty As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dicty

    dick = kvp.Key
    dicv = kvp.Value

    Next
```

dick is the string with keys and dicv the one with values.

But I receive error "string cannot be converted to string()" when assigning dick and dicv as kvp.key and kvp.value.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That is pulling a key and value *out* of the dictionary, not assigning as the post states.  The declarations for the others would be useful since one is apparently not a string at all.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from the error that dick and dicv are declared as arrays. The following is how you assign values to arrays. ArrayVariable(index) = value

```
Private Sub ConvertDictionaryToArrays()
        Dim dicty As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim dick(dicty.Count - 1) As String
        Dim dicv(dicty.Count - 1) As String
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dicty
            dick(index) = kvp.Key
            dicv(index) = kvp.Value
            index += 1
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't do anything as `dicty` is an empty Dictionary. The OP appears to want to use the existing contents of the `dick` and `dicv` arrays to create the values in the Dictionary.

Comment: @Blackwood Oops! Got it backwards. I assumed from the code it was the other way around and the code filling the dictionary had simply been omitted.

Comment: This worked very well!! I created two arrays from the split strings and populated the dictionary from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub FillDictionary()
    Dim dicty As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim dick(39) As String 'Guess that you have both of these arrays
    Dim dicv(39) As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To dick.Length - 1
        dicty.Add(dick(i), dicv(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```